# Visual studio error: No module named 'flask_wtf'

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015

I i’m using visual studio for flask project and when running it i’m getting error **No module named 'flask_wtf**'

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required
```

This shows in command line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FlaskWebProject14\Fl
askWebProject14\app.py", line 7, in <module>
    from forms import ContactForm
  File "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FlaskWebProject14\Fl
askWebProject14\forms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_wtf import Form
ImportError: No module named 'flask_wtf'
```

I have:

- Python version 3.6.0a4
- Flask 0.12.1
- Visual Studio 2015
- Installed flask-wtf with pip (pip install flask-wtf)

What’s the solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's because python cannot find that package in you env. You can change your env that contains the package. For quick workaround though, you can install the package in you current directory. That way you can get away without modifying your env. Try this:

`pip install --target=<your_project_location> package_name`

In your case `<your_project_location>` will be `C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FlaskWebProject14\FlaskWebProject14` and `package_name` will be `Flask-WTF`